# Probability that no two of the chosen balls lie on any straight line

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Consider $10$ black balls arranged as shown in the image. Of these $10$ balls, three distinct balls are chosen at random. Compute the probability that no two of the chosen balls lie on any straight line drawn in the figure.

[image]

I don't even know how to start solving this problem. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** I think the following choice of vertices - $5$, $3$ and $7$ is a valid choice.[image]

**EDIT 2:** With the help of some of the discussions we had in the comments, the straight line mentioned in the question should be an edge. So, no two vertices should lie on the same edge.

Comment: There's a very easy way to start: Draw all possible choices of three balls. Count the totsl number of drawings. Count the number of draeings where no two of the three chosen balls are on a straight line. Divide.

Comment: *... don't even know how to start ...* is not likely to get you help . You need to show whatever effort you have put in, however inconclusive it might be.

Comment: Say, mention that you know how many possibilities there are to choose 3 out of 10, yielding the denominator.

Comment: Might help to note that choosing a note is the same as choosing two distinct lines.  Altogether, you are asked to choose $6$ distinct lines, in pairs.

Comment: @trueblueanil Actually, I am confused about what lying on a straight line means. Is it that the two balls lie on a single edge or they can be joined by multiple edges like for example the two vertices in the extreme left and right side.

Comment: @meme   All the lines are shown.  The undrawn lines don't count.  If they did, then of course the probability would be $0$ since any two points are on a common line.

Comment: @lulu Yes, that's what I was thinking, the probability should be zero in that case.

Comment: But, that really can't be what the problem is asking, since in that case the drawn figure would be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us calculate the probability if we mean that no two balls are the ends of the same edge. Consider the inner $5$ vertices. It’s obvious that if all three balls are put there, then there will be an edge with two balls. So only $0$, $1$ or $2$ balls can be there.

If $0$ balls occupy the central vertices, then the $3$ balls can be put in any of the $5$ outer vertices. There are $\binom53$ such combinations.

If $1$ ball is put in a central vertex (there are $5$ ways to do that), then the two other balls can occupy any of the $3$ outer vertices. So, $5\cdot \binom32$ ways in this case.

Finally, consider the case when two balls are put in central vertices. They can’t be neighbours, so they are always put as neighbours to one empty vertex (3 and 7 in your picture). There are $5$ ways to do that. There is only one vacant outer vertex left (5 in your picture), and it gets occupied with the third ball.

Hence the answer is $$\frac{\binom53+ 5\cdot \binom32+5}{\binom{10}3}=\frac14.$$

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think in the 3rd case, there are 6 ways to put two balls in the central vertices - $\{3, 10\}, \{3, 7\}, \{2, 7\}, \{2, 9\}, \{9, 3\}, \{9, 10\}$

Comment: @meme $\{9$, $3\}$ is wrong in your list.

Comment: @meme What you really should do is to edit your question to include a correct understanding of the term “straight line”.

Comment: Aah yes, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that there are only two types of balls. For both types individually, notice that choosing a ball of this type blocks seven balls (being on the same line as the chosen ball). The remaining three balls are on a triangle. So any choice of two balls gives you two balls on a line.

This means that there are 0 possibilities to choose three balls such that no two balls are on a line.

This means the probability is 0.

**EDIT**

Here are pictures illustrating the above. We choose the green ball. This blocks the red balls because they are on the same line as the green ball. So we have to choose two of the orange balls. But since the orange balls form a triangle (using the drawn lines), any choice of two orange balls leads to the two balls being on a (drawn) line.

This is the situation when we choose (any) one of the outer balls (say this is type 1).
[image]

This is the situation when we choose (any) one of the inner balls (say this is type 2).
[image]

Comment: It does. I see five lines, no more, no less.

Comment: @reyna I think the question meant the specific lines that are drawn. Otherwise, the probability is 0 which doesn't look right.

Comment: The probability is still zero though. At least I don't see a valid choice.

Comment: To stress:  Since choosing a node is the same as choosing two distinct lines (the node being the intersection), the problem asks you to choose $6$ distinct lines.  Alas, there are only $5$.  Just for a different argument.

Comment: @Matija Can you check the edit which I think is a valid choice

Comment: @meme How is that a valid choice, if balls 3 and 5 are on the same straight (horizontal) line 5-2-3-4?

Comment: @Aig I am assuming the straight lines are just the edges of the graph. 5-2-3-4 can't be a straight line (as per my assumption) because it consists of multiple edges. There is some ambiguity in the question about what they mean by straight line, is it a single edge or a path which is straight in the graph drawn as in the picture. The probability is 0 in the latter case as Matija showed but I think the question assumes the former i.e., straight line is a single edge. Then only we will get a non-trivial answer.

Comment: @meme I agree that it would be strange to have $0$ as an answer. It is a good supposition that they probably meant an edge by a straight line.